# Excel - Index Match on Array Not Returning Correct Answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of labor force statistics ('State Labor Force') broken down by state, year, and type of stat (there are 4 types of stats). See the screenshot below:

[image: Lookup table]

I then have a second table where I allow a user to input each of these 3 search parameters and have it return the value (for example, from the screenshot above, Alabama's 2000 Labor Force would equal 2133233). However, for some reason the index match keeps returning 0.

```
=INDEX('State Labor Force'!$D:$D,
MATCH($H$79&$G80&$B$78,
'State Labor Force'!$A:$A&'State Labor Force'!$B:$B&'State Labor Force'!$C:$C,0))
```

(where `H79` = state input, `G80` = year input, and `B78` = stat input; all 3 are tied to list validations and there are no spelling errors).

Anybody have any idea why this formula would not be working?

Comment: Define "formula not working". What are you expecting the result to be for a specific input? What is the result actually? My guess (just based on what the problem typically is) is that the value you are trying to look up in `MATCH` does not exist anywhere in the list where you are trying to look up from. Could also be that you need to enter as an array formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula should look like this (Ctrl + Shift + Enter, for making it to an array formula):

```
{=INDEX('State Labor Force'!$D:$D,
MATCH(1,($H$79='State Labor Force'!$A:$A)*($G80='State Labor Force'!$B:$B)*($B$78='State Labor Force'!$C:$C),0))}
```

The idea behind a index + match formula with multiple criteria goes as follow:

```
{=INDEX(Result Range,MATCH(1,(A1=range1)*(B2=range2)*(C3=range3),0))}
```

Where:

`Result Range` = The range you want to return your final result

`Range1` = range of criteria 1, where you define criteria 1 in A1

`Range2` = range of criteria 2, where you define criteria 2 in B2

`Range3` = range of criteria 3, where you define criteria 3 in C3

`0` = exact match to return

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Enter for array formula. Ctrl+Enter isn't array formula. But otherwise I agree with your answer. +1

Comment: You are correct, missed the "Shift" and bad English from my part :P. Thank you :)!

Comment: Also, something worth mentioning: If possible, full column references (e.g. `A:A`) should be avoided if possible when multiplying arrays together. The only time you can use full column references without a performance penalty is when you use the `IF` functions such as `COUNTIF`,`SUMIF`,`AVERAGEIF`, etc. If possible, `$A:$A` should be reduced to `$A$1:$A$100`, for example.

Comment: It turns out Excel may have been a little tired of me because I restarted the program and it finally seems to be working. I switched to using your "*" formula instead of the "&" I had been using, and it appears to be working for now. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, fun to help you :)! My excel is so tired of me too, aahahah ;). Glad it solved your problem!.

Answer (score 1):

1. That construction needs to be committed as an **array formula****
2. You are missing a `FALSE` (or, equivalently, `0`) for `MATCH`'s *match_type* parameter

As such:

`=INDEX('State Labor Force'!$D:$D,MATCH($H$79&$G80&$B$78,'State Labor Force'!$A:$A&'State Labor Force'!$B:$B&'State Labor Force'!$C:$C,0))`

However, by referencing entire columns within such a construction you are forcing Excel to calculate an astonishing number of cells (more than 3 million) for a single formula.

Far better would be to perform the concatenations within an additional column within the worksheet, after which you can use a non-array `INDEX`/`MATCH` construction which will be far, far faster to calculate. For example, using column E of the *State Labor Force* tab for this purpose, we would enter, in `E2`:

`=A2&B2&C2`

after which you can use simply:

`=INDEX('State Labor Force'!$D:$D,MATCH($H$79&$G80&$B$78,'State Labor Force'!$E:$E,0))`

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: For the record, I had been using an array formula in Excel. I just rewrote the formula for purposes of the original post and didn't include the brackets. Appreciate the response to my question anyway.